# fastCgi request timeout vs PHP max_execution_time

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I'm running PHP on IIS 7.5 in a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Currently my `fastCgi request timeout` is set to 90 seconds in IIS.

But the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` is set to 30.

What would happen in that case? Will the script crash but the request be kept in the requests queue until it finishes once it reaches 90 seconds ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put the same value on both. Or the max of your multi-site config :
2. After, in the main php.ini, you can add

[PATH=C:/inetpub/website1.com/]

max_execution_time = 60

[PATH=C:/inetpub/website2.com/]

max_execution_time = 200

3. After that you can verify with phpinfo function :
   Create a PHP file with the following text :

Open the page in browser and find :
[image]